# How do I make Contact Form 7 pop up in thickbox?

Tags: jquery, plugin-contact-form-7, thickbox

I am trying to make contact form 7 pop up in a thickbox modal window. I can either use `do_shortcode` or the shortcode but I'm not sure how to set it up. Can someone push me in the right direction?

From the [Thickbox page](http://thickbox.net/), it looks like I should be using either inline Content, iFramed Content, or AJAX Content, but I'm not sure which one.

Comment: I found that the PopPop! plugin works really well with CF7 in terms of compatibility with themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution I can think of is creating an almost empty page template that contains the bare minimum `header`, `body` (your shortcode) and `footer`.

Create a page with this template and load iFramed.

Like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Almost Empty Page for Thickbox
 */

// REPLACE THIS get_header WITH THE CONTENTS OF THE FILE header.php
// AND CLEAN UP EVERYTHING THAT'S NOT NEEDED
get_header(); 
?>
    <div id="container" class="one-column">
        <div id="content" role="main">
        <?php
            do_shortcode(); // YOUR SHORTCODE
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 
// REPLACE THIS get_footer WITH THE CONTENTS OF THE FILE footer.php AND CLEAN UP
get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: By "cleaned" header.php and footer.php, I am assuming I should create a new version and call it like: `<?php get_header('thickbox'); ?>`?

Comment: I've edited the Answer. When I do this, I prefer to make it bundled in only one file, but, yes you could go the `get_header` way.

Comment: I created cleaned up versions for `header-thickbox.php`, a `footer-thickbox.php` and called them from `thickbox.php` (the template in your example). However, when I do this, I get this error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in thickbox.php on line 7` Any ideas where I could have gone wrong?

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: Does the page loads independently? If you navigate to the permalink? Try to load it in a regular `iframe`....

Comment: `<sorry>out of options here</sorry>`